# Can you have as many <nav> 's as you want in a HTML 5 document?

Tags: html

I like the new tags from the HTML 5 standard. Can I use them more than once?

Like 3 `<nav>` tags, or two `<sidebar>` tags, and can I invent new tags like `<fuu>` ?

In xhtml I had:

```
<div class="nav-wrap">
 <div class="nav">
   ...
 </div>
</div>
```

so I could do something like:

```
<nav class="wrap">
  <nav>  <!-- can <nav> have <li>'s ? -->
  ...
  </nav>
</nav>
```

?

Comment: Is your question related to any specific search engine and/or application?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `<nav>` element is defined in the [html5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/spec.html), but the `<sidebar>` element is not. You can use as many `<nav>` elements as you'd like (so long as they aren't nested), but the other ones you'd have to provide a DTD and hope that the browser your users use is flexible enough to accept new elements.

I would recommend *not* defining new elements, and just use the existing semantic elements to create the effects you are after.

`<div class="sidebar"></div>` is good enough and will be treated as secondary content if you're wrapping your primary content in `<main>`, which effectively cues the browser into understanding that the region is not a header, footer, or primary content, which on most sites equates to a sidebar.

However, in most cases, the `<aside>` element is appropriate for use as a sidebar.

[Per the spec:](http://w3c.github.io/html/sections.html#the-aside-element)

> The aside element represents a section of a page that consists of content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside element, and which could be considered separate from that content. **Such sections are often represented as sidebars in printed typography**.

<sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

Comment: In addition to this, the nav tag is meant for containing links so it can not be nested. but you can have nav tag as many you need. ideally we do have two nav tag in the page one in header section and other in footer. see here[link](http://www.w3.org/2009/cheatsheet/#search,nav)

Answer (score 5):

The 'nav' element should be used wherever there is 'main' navigation going on, usually that's in the header of your website, but it can also be in places where you let the user navigate the current page.

It's normally not needed to put it in your footer (as it's not usually considered your primary navigation), although it can't really hurt.

zzzzBov's answer is not entirely correct, so let me try to give a more accurate example.

As alternative for 'sidebar', you should use the 'aside' tag, which normally contains secondary content (like side navigation, links, ad's, things like that).

```
<div class="sidebar"></div>
```

This is **not** semantically a sidebar, far from it. The div element is used as a hook for styling or JavaScript and has no semantic meaning, that's why the 'aside' element was introduced, please use that!

If you only need a wrapper for styling, then a div is perfect (even preferred).

As a rule of thumb, your HTML should contain elements that *describe* your content. You can usually read it out loud and it will make sense.

For example: "I have a list of navigation elements on the side of my page", would translate to:

```
<aside>
  <nav>
    <h1>Navigation</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/someplace">Link to someplace</li>
      <li><a href="/someplace-else">Link to someplace else</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>
```

So to summarize: in general you use the nav element on major navigation area's, like the navigation found in the header of websites and sometimes navigation found to navigate the current page.

Sections of a page that are not your main content (but might be related) are usually put in an 'aside' element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `aside` is not always the semantically correct element for a sidebar.

Comment: That's correct, but a div has no semantics anyway. The sidebar as a whole doesn't need a new element (a div will be fine to controls it's appearance), but the content in the sidebar might benefit from elements like aside and nav.

Comment: A `div` has no implicit semantics, but a `[class]` does. `class="sidebar"` gives the `div` some meaning, in that it now belongs to the group of sidebars. These semantics are usually transparent to end-users, but are important for web-development in general. When the `<main>` element was being discussed for inclusion, one factor in determining its usefulness was the data from existing sites that made use of classes such as `.main`, `.content`, etc. For the most part the elements used were `div`s, but they still had semantics.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I don't agree with the word "semantic" in this case.

On a user and browser level, divs and spans communicate no semantics wahtsoever, regardless of their classes. For developers this is different, but it only expresses "semantics" as a way of letting other developers know what the purpose of that div/span is.

The main element was included mainly (no pun intended) to separate the actual main content from the rest of the flow, something aria-roles already did. A `<div class="sidebar">` has no other meaning in regards to accessibility for example.

Comment: Semantics don't have to be for accessibility. For example, the hCard microformat will often go ignored, even though it absolutely adds meaning to a document.

Comment: Yes, again, I think you're using the word "semantic" in a much broader context (which is fine), but in this particular case there are no extra implied semantics when using a class.

To stay on point of the question: if you want to mark-up a sidebar "semantically", there's simply no element for that. However, using proper elements inside the sidebar (such as asides) will certainly help.

Just to keep the scope of "semantic" useful, otherwise every piece of data has semantics ;-)

Comment: As I was reviewing some old answers of mine, I've stumbled on this older thread. I've decided that upon further reflection that I was wrong for a variety of reasons, much of which is to your point that I was using the word "semantic" incorrectly. I had previously used it in its general sense of "meaning", rather than what is conventional jargon to stand for "a browser's automatically interpretable meaning for general use assisting users".

Answer (score 1):

It's more common to nest an unordered list of links within your `nav`:

```
<nav class="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li>...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

You can have as many `nav` elements as you need in your page, but you don't need to wrap every link or set of links in a `nav` - only 'major navigation' should be in a `nav` element.  There's a [good introduction to `nav` in this HTML5 Doctor post](http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/).

For sidebars there's no need to invent your own element, use the [`aside` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-aside-element) for them.

You can invent your own elements and still have your markup work in an HTML5 compliant browser, the [HTML5 tokenization algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tokenization.html#tag-name-state) doesn't care about what tag names you use as long as they follow the rules, but you wouldn't then be writing HTML5 so it's sort of pointless.  I recommend having a read through the section ["Conformance requirements for authors"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.html#conformance-requirements-for-authors) at the start of the spec, particularly the bit "Cases that are likely to be typos":

> When a user makes a simple typo, it is
>   helpful if the error can be caught
>   early, as this can save the author a
>   lot of debugging time. This
>   specification therefore usually
>   considers it an error to use element
>   names, attribute names, and so forth,
>   that do not match the names defined in
>   this specification.